# How to show the following line are coplanar?

Tags: geometry

I am stuck on the following problem:

> Show that the lines $$\frac{px}{l}=\frac{qy}{m}=\frac{rz}{n},\frac{x}{l}=\frac{y}{m}=\frac{z}{n} ,\frac{x}{pl}=\frac{y}{qm}=\frac{z}{rn}$$ are coplanar if $p=q $ or $q=r$ or $r=p$.

My Try:  Let the aforementioned lines lie on the plane : $ax+by+cz+d=0$. Then

$$\frac{al}{p}+\frac{bm}{q}+\frac{cn}{r}+d=0 \tag 1$$

$$al+bm+cn+d=0 \tag 2$$ and $$apl+bqm+crn +d=0 \tag 3$$

So, eliminating a,b,c from $(1),(2),(3)$, we get

$\begin{vmatrix}
l/p & m/q &n/r \\ 
 l& m & n\\ 
pl &qm  & rn
\end{vmatrix}=0 \implies qr(r-q)+pr(p-r)+pq(q-p)=0$ and this is the condition for coplanarity. Now,for$ p=q$, we see  $qr(r-q)+pr(p-r)+pq(q-p)=0$ and hence proved. Similarly for others. Am I right?

Comment: You are right but I would do it a little bit simpler. All lines pass through the origin and it’s enough to prove that direction vectors of these lines are coplanar. That condition is exactly captured in the determinant equation that you wrote. The rest is just execution.

Comment: Three co-planar vectors have their triple product equal zero $a\cdot(b \times c)=0$ if $a$, $b$ and $c$ are co-planar.